# Взаимное присваивание столбцов внутри DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Классический вопрос больше для познания, чем решения конкретной проблемы. Где-то видел замечания на эту тему в официальной документации pandas, но без объяснения сути. Итак, есть датафрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]})
print(df)

    a   b
0   1   5
1   2   4
2   3   3
3   4   2
4   5   1
```

Рабочий код:

```
df[['b', 'a']] = df[['a', 'b']]
print(df)

   a  b
0  5  1
1  4  2
2  3  3
3  2  4
4  1  5
```

Если действуем через `loc`, то не работает:

```
df.loc[:, ['b', 'a']] = df[['a', 'b']]
print(df)

    a   b
0   1   5
1   2   4
2   3   3
3   4   2
4   5   1
```

Как работает взаимное присваивание столбцов внутри DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При работе с DataFrame'ами Pandas пытается делать выравнивание по именам столбцов и по значениям индексов.

Поэтому при выполнении:

```
df.loc[:, ['b', 'a']] = df[['a', 'b']]
```

Pandas присвоит значения соответствующим столбцам, т.е. столбцу `a` присвоятся значения столбца `a`, тоже самое произойдет со столбцом `b`.

Честно говоря я не совсем понимаю почему выравнивание не срабатывает при таком варианте:

```
df[['b', 'a']] = df[['a', 'b']]
```

Чтобы поменять значения столбцов достаточно с правой стороны от знака присваивания превратить DataFrame в Numpy 2D NDArray. Т.к. у Numpy 2D NDArray отсутствуют имена столбцов, Pandas присвоит их последовательно столбцам, стоящим с левой стороны от знака присвивания (проверив предварительно на совпадение размерностей):

```
In [91]: df.loc[:, ['b', 'a']] = df[['a', 'b']].values

In [92]: df
Out[92]:
   a  b
0  5  1
1  4  2
2  3  3
3  2  4
4  1  5
```